# How to Install previous version of bootstrap using npm

Tags: angular

I want to install the previous version of bootstrap in angular 2.

when I am using the following command in the terminal window in VS code then it installs bootstrap 4 version but I want to have bootstrap 3

```
 $ npm install bootstrap
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`npm install bootstrap@3.0.0 --save-dev`

Comment: You should properly remove `--save-dev`

Answer (score 0):

`npm install bootstrap@3 --save-dev`
 Make sure to include `"../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"` in your `angular-cli.json` styles

Comment: You should properly remove `--save-dev`